# $.extend() = not extending when used with server loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, object, extend

I am trying to create 2 blank objects, run a php loop that fills 1 of them, and then extend the objects together... ultimately to create 1 object with many objects inside.

Here's the logic/code (note, the server stuff is proprietary but it runs off php and is working fine):

```
var allUsers = {};
var singleUser = {};

$(document).ready(function(){

<fm:UserList 
    fields="id,firstname,lastname,geo_latitude,geo_longitude,meta,externalids"
> 

    <fm:Loop> 

        singleUser = {
            'index'             : '{$loop.index}',
            'id'                : '{$user.id}',
            'firstname'         : '{$user.firstname}',
            'lastname'          : '{$user.lastname}',
            'geo_latitude'      : '{$user.geo_latitude}',
            'geo_longitude'     : '{$user.geo_longitude}',
            'company'           : '{$user.meta.company}',
            'twitter'           : '{$user.meta.twitter}',
            'externalprovider'  : '{$user.externalids.0.external_id_provider}',
            'externalid'        : '{$user.externalids.0.external_parsed_id}'

        }
        /* Merge singleUser into allUsers */
        $.extend(allUsers,singleUser);

    </fm:Loop>
</fm:UserList>

console.log(allUsers);
});
```

Here is what get's put on the page:

```
var allUsers = {};
var setUser = {};

    $(document).ready(function(){

        setUser = {
            'index'             : '0',
            'id'                : '1930039',
            'firstname'         : 'Devo',
            'lastname'          : 'Brown',
            'geo_latitude'      : '-46.81610453612681',
            'geo_longitude'     : '-70.6640625',
            'company'           : 'Filemobile',
            'twitter'           : 'devinbrownca',
            'externalprovider'  : '',
            'externalid'        : ''

        }
        /* Merge setUser into passed allUsers */
        $.extend(allUsers,setUser);



        setUser = {
            'index'             : '1',
            'id'                : '1930025',
            'firstname'         : 'Aidan',
            'lastname'          : 'Roach',
            'geo_latitude'      : '51.032184898096396',
            'geo_longitude'     : '-108.6328125',
            'company'           : '',
            'twitter'           : '',
            'externalprovider'  : '',
            'externalid'        : ''

        }
        /* Merge setUser into passed allUsers */
        $.extend(allUsers,setUser);



        setUser = {
            'index'             : '2',
            'id'                : '1930024',
            'firstname'         : 'Devin',
            'lastname'          : 'Brown ',
            'geo_latitude'      : '42.89743256946478',
            'geo_longitude'     : '-101.6015625',
            'company'           : '',
            'twitter'           : '',
            'externalprovider'  : '',
            'externalid'        : ''

        }
        /* Merge setUser into passed allUsers */
        $.extend(allUsers,setUser);

console.log(allUsers);
});
```

At the end of the function, the console only logs a single object, the last object created.

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$.extend` is copying properties of one object to another.

I guess you need an array

```
var allUsers = [];

 /* Push singleUser into allUsers */
 allUsers.push(singleUser);
```

Answer (score 2):

What $.extend does is merging the contents (fields) of two or more objects together into the first object. It seems that allUsers should be not a hash (object) but an array.
So you'll push users into it:

```
var allUsers = [];

allUsers.push(singleUser);
```

Answer (score 1):

This behavior is exactly what `extend` does.  Any new property of the `setUser` object gets added to `allUsers`, but existing properties get overwritten. For example:

```
    setUser = {
        'firstname'         : 'Devo',
        'index'             : '0',
    }
    $.extend(allUsers,setUser);

    setUser = {
        'index'             : '1',
        'id'                : '1930039'
    }
    $.extend(allUsers,setUser);
```

would result in the following object:

```
    allUsers = {
        'firstname'         : 'Devo',
        'index'             : '1',
        'id'                : '1930039'
    }
```

So, the question is:  What do want this code to do?

If you simply want to keep track of all users, you might just want to keep an array of `setUser` objects, as such:

```
allUsers = [
            {
               'id':'0',
                ...
            },
            {
               'id':'1',
                ...
            },
            {
               'id':'2',
               ...
            }
           ];
```

You could achieve this by just pushing every `setUser` object into an `allUsers` array, as such:

```
allUsers = [];

setUser = {...};
allUsers.push(setUser);
```

If however, you would like one `allUsers` object with an array of values for each property, like this:

```
    allUsers = {
        'firstname'         : ['Devo', 'Aidan'],
        'index'             : ['0','1'],
        ...
    }
```

You would need to roll your own function.

Another solution to your problem could be to keep `allUsers` as an object, but use keys for each user object:

```
allUsers = {
    '1930039' = {
        'index'             : '0',
        'firstname'         : 'Devo',
        'lastname'          : 'Brown',
        ...
    },
    '1930025' = {
        'index'             : '1',
        'firstname'         : 'Aidan',
        'lastname'          : 'Roach',
        ...
    },
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var allUsers = [];
var singleUser = {};

$(document).ready(function(){
<fm:UserList 
    fields="id,firstname,lastname,geo_latitude,geo_longitude,meta,externalids"
    geo="notnull"
> 

    <fm:Loop> 

        singleUser = {
            'index'             : '{$loop.index}',
            'id'                : '{$user.id}',
            'firstname'         : '{$user.firstname}',
            'lastname'          : '{$user.lastname}',
            'geo_latitude'      : '{$user.geo_latitude}',
            'geo_longitude'     : '{$user.geo_longitude}',
            'company'           : '{$user.meta.company}',
            'twitter'           : '{$user.meta.twitter}',
            'externalprovider'  : '{$user.externalids.0.external_id_provider}',
            'externalid'        : '{$user.externalids.0.external_parsed_id}'

        }
        /* push singleUser object into allUsers array */
        allUsers.push(singleUser);
    </fm:Loop>
</fm:UserList>
```